# Android Two fragments one screen, one with a canvas

Tags: android, android-fragments, canvas

Relatively new to Android development and have been struggling with this. My problem is to have two fragments on the same page. The top fragment needs to just display some text and the bottom fragment needs to display a canvas which will draw lines. I need both to be observable at the same time.

From what I have done, I can get the bottom fragment to draw lines just fine, but it covers the entire screen. I believe this happens when I do the following in the bottom fragment:

```
getActivity().setContentView(drawView);
```

How do I get it to only show on the bottom fragment and not display over the entire screen? Example code would be very beneficial for me.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use two views within one fragment?

Comment: I honestly don't know how putting views within one fragment would be better. Nor which views would work. If I need a basic canvas on the bottom view, would I implement something like SurfaceView?

Comment: All views have a canvas that can be manipulated within the `onDraw` method.

Comment: In that case would it be better to not use a fragment and instead use an activity?

Comment: Also, I do not know how to manipulate the SurfaceView with onDraw. When I create a new drawView, it uses the context from the activity and draws on the entire screen.

Comment: Is this task still possible to do with two fragments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setContentView will replace whatever is already there.

First you have to make two container slots for the fragment. Put this in your activities layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ></RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ></RelativeLayout>
```

Then you need to set that layout as the activity layout in your activity java file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this line will set layout from the xml layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Then place the fragments inside the slots:
    Fragment myFrag = new TopFragment();
    Fragment myFrag = new BottomFragment();

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer1,new TopFragment()).commit();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer2,new BottomFragment()).commit();
```

There are other ways of doing too , depending on if you want to declare everything in xml.

Comment: What do you mean by "place the fragments inside the slots:"? What are the slots?

Comment: After looking at the documentation more closely about Fragments, what you posted makes a lot more sense and works for my problem. Thank you for you help!